# Scan Documents in Silverlight In-Browser application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, scanning, wia

How can i connect to scanner and scan a document in silverlight in-browser application?!

My Application run on Intranet and all clients use windows as operating system.

- Any way Or code is there to do this?
- Any Component
- Java Script code

Have an idea or a way to do this?

My Application run on Intranet and all clients use windows as operating system.
I use silverlight 5 in-browser application!

Comment: Is it an intranet/LOB app or a public application? If it's internal, and Windows only, you could try in browser elevated trust, which would give you P/Invoke/COM interop.

Comment: Yes, It is an Intranet/LOB app. How can  i use P/Invoke/COM interop to connect scanner?!!

Comment: Well you get access to the same methods unmanaged code has on Windows. So you need a SDK to get images from supported sources.